# Querying Fiware COSMOS generates RemoteException for node in safe mode

Tags: python, hadoop, fiware-cosmos

Querying COSMOS by Hive with this python script:

```
import pyhs2

with pyhs2.connect(host='cosmos.lab.fiware.org',
                    port=10000,
                    authMechanism="PLAIN",
                    user='glaquidara',
                    password='*****',
                    database='default') as conn:
     with conn.cursor() as cur:
         cur.execute("select * from glaquidara_mazzi")
         print cur.getSchema()

         for i in cur.fetch():
             print i
```

generates the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "libra.py", line 10, in 
>           cur.execute("select * from glaquidara_mazzi")
>         File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyhs2/cursor.py", line 64, in execute
>           raise Pyhs2Exception(res.status.errorCode, res.status.errorMessage)
>       pyhs2.error.Pyhs2Exception: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot
>   create directory
>   /tmp/hive-root/hive_2015-10-07_13-32-30_348_3807878262746902303-`3.
>   Name node is in safe mode.\nResources are low on NN. Safe mode must be
>   turned off manually.\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2140)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2114)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mkdirs(NameNode.java:892)\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor586.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)\n\tat
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1439)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1435)\n\tat
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)\n\tat
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1433)\n'`

What is the problem with this?

Comment: The cluster automatically entered in safe mode for a while. This is currently fixed.

Comment: This question should be closed, nevertheless not enough "deletion" flags in my account.